# How can I control a CSS animation with restart and status feedback in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm trying to migrate a CSS animation from a vanilla code to a vue code. So far I have found a solution. However, I think that my vue solution is not optimal and there may be a better option.

Specifically, I want a message to disappear by itself after a certain period of time. Exception is when there is a hover event. Then the message is to be displayed until the event is pending. After that, the fade out animation is restarted.

Furthermore, if possible with vue, I want the current state (visible, invisible) to be saved in the state of my application. Is this possible with vue transitions?

```js
// vanilla code
let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let message = document.getElementById('message');
  message.classList.remove('message-animation');
  void message.offsetWidth; // vanilla solution to re-render
  message.classList.add('message-animation');
}, false);

// vue code
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Vue message. Move the mouse over me to prevent me from disappearing.',
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
    showMessage: function() {
      let self = this;
      this.show = false;
      Vue.nextTick(function () { // vue solution to re-render
        self.show = true;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.message {
  background: silver;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.message-animation {
  animation: message-animation-keyframes 3s linear;
}

.message-animation:hover {
  animation: 0;
  height: 24px;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes message-animation-keyframes {
  0%, 66% {
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- vanilla markup -->
<div>
  <button id="button">Show vanilla message</button>
  <p class="message" id="message">Vanilla message. Move the mouse over me to prevent me from disappearing.</p>
</div>

<!-- vue markup -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="showMessage">Show vue message</button>
  <p class="message" :class="{ 'message-animation': show }" v-if="show">{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pending"?

Comment: @zero298: I mean that the message should be visible as long as the user is over it with the mouse. So as long as the hover event is active.